# How to pass API gateway context variable to proxy lambda

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I am looking for guidance on how to pass the API Gateway context variable (for example: $context.RequestTime) to the proxy lamba.

Basically I want to send the time request has reached in Api gateway to my lambda proxy method as a request header.

Note that I am using serverless framework (serverless.com)

I tried the following but it does not work

```
events:
 - http:
     path: /{proxy+}
     method: ANY
     request:
      parameters:
        paths:
          proxy: true
        headers: 
          requestTime: $context.requestTime
```

Comment: Did you try use proxy integration and velocity template language? I might be mistaken but your problems looks like it can be done with those.

Comment: please share if you have some examples on how it can be done with serverless

Comment: I meant the non-default "lambda integration" (I think) and not the default "lambda-proxy integration", so that you make a mapping with velocity template language in API gateway. https://medium.com/@lakshmanLD/lambda-proxy-vs-lambda-integration-in-aws-api-gateway-3a9397af0e6d There might be easier ways and I am not sure it is right, but I had to use it for something which appeared similar to your problem.

Comment: I need to get it working using proxy integration and serverless framework.

Comment: I realized that API Gateway is passing RequestTimeEpoch in the request context object to the Lambda. I was interested in RequestTimeEpoch only, and the issue is solved now.